# How to use JavaScript to determine whether a file exists in a directory?

Tags: javascript, file

How to use javascript to determine whether a file exists in a directory?

Comment: What kind of file and where is the directory, server or client?

Answer (score 11):

If it's on the server, you could make an [HTTP HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request via Ajax, and look if the HTTP Status Code is [404](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5) (Not found) or [200](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.1) (Ok).

An example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'HEAD',
  url: 'somefile.ext',
  complete: function (xhr){
    if (xhr.status == 404){
      alert(xhr.statusText); // Not found
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: nice. never thought of this one :)

Answer (score 6):

If the JavaScript is running in a web browser, you do not have access to the local filesystem. If there were a way to get access to the local filesystem, it would be considered a security hole that would be fixed by the browser vendor.

Comment: does a firefox extension count as "in a web browser" ? You can access the filesystem from there.

Comment: An extension is not running *in* a web browser, it is running *as part of* a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an elegant way to do this, but for a lightweight solution you could try and load the file as the src to an Image object, and handle the [onerror](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onError.asp) event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var folderPath="set you path here";
//to check whether folder exists
fso.FolderExists(folderPath)) 
//to check whether file exists          
alert(fso.FileExists(folderPath+ "\\<filename>"));
```

[How to use JavaScript to determine whether a directory exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940394/how-to-use-javascript-to-determine-whether-a-directory-exists/6940456#6940456)