# How to use JavaScript to determine whether a directory exists?

Tags: javascript

I have written the following code to write a file on my local file system:

```
writeToFile : function(msg) {
    var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    fh = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\QHHH\\myXML.xml", true);
    fh.WriteLine(msg);
    fh.Close();
}
```

What I want now is to check if the directory(the one I have specified in code snippet above) even exists or not already? I want to throw an exception or simply show an alert to the user that "Please specify a directory you want to store your file into" and anything like this.
So my questions are:
**1.Is it possible to check if the specified directory exists or not ?

2.Is it possible to create the directory on the fly and store the file in there automatically?**

Please don't bother that accessing local file system is bad or anything else. I am creating this for my own personal use and I am well aware of this fact.

Please try to answer in native javascript, I am not using JQuery or any other framework.

Many Thanks

Comment: activeX might do the trick, but only works in IE, consider to do applet?

Comment: I am using IE8.Any code specific to IE will be perfect for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
var sFolderPath = "c:\\QHHH";
if (!fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath)) {
    alert("Folder does not exist!");
    return;
}

fh = fso.CreateTextFile(sFolderPath + "\\myXML.xml", true);
//....
```

Comment: This is perfect.Thankyou very much.Can I create a directory on the fly?

Answer (score 2):

To create a directory all you need is :

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
fso.CreateFolder("fully qualified name of the forlder u want 2 create");
```

Comment: the answer is already provided, be careful next time.Thanks for help BTW.

Comment: oops ...  very sorry.I'll be careful next time.Thanks.